# Ubuntu 21.10 can't find bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, 21.10

I'm trying to activate the Bluetooth option in my computer (ASUS ROG Strix G513QR, Ubuntu 21.10), but it does not recognize an internal BT device.
I tried many commands and installations that I found online, but none of them worked.

Results of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; rfkill list` :

[image: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; rfkill list output]

You can also see that `hcitool dev` finds nothing.

Comment: Did you try `sudo systemctl enable --now bluetooth` and `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` ? EDIT: I see that bluetooth is not blocked by rfkill in your screenshot...

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service` and then go to the terminal and type `bluetoothctl`. After getting into it, type `scan on` and see if your bluetooth devices are visible.